# HTML special characters are not showing properly in js

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters, alert

I am developing a web application using PHP,Smarty for a french client.  I am facing a problem in java script alert and confirm boxes. How can I use HTML special characters in javascript message boxes. This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function delConfirm(key){

        if(confirm('&Ecirc;tes vous certain de vouloir supprimer ce client ?')){
            window.location = "deleteClient.php?e="+key;
        }

    }
</script>
```

This is the page source of the first part of the page. Please take a look at the encoding section too,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Sunil">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's correct, because `confirm` doesn't accept HTML. You can use unicode escape sequence in JavaScript, though. You can look up Unicode code point values [here](http://unicode.org/). The equivalent of `&Ecirc;` is `U+00CA` (it's on [this chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf)), so:

```
if(confirm('\u00CAtes vous certain de vouloir supprimer ce client ?')){
    window.location = "deleteClient.php?e="+key;
}
```

Alternately, ensure that your file is correctly encoded (in UTF-8 for example), that your editor understands files encoded in that way, and that the file is served correctly (the server tells the browser it's UTF-8), maybe even throw in a [`meta charset="xxx"` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-charset) in the header for luck, and you can just type the French characters directly into the file.

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion. Could u plz show me the code to display such a message ('&Ecirc;tes vous certain de vouloir supprimer ce client ?') in alert box?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. I have updated the question with page source. Please take a look in it. Is the encoding correct ? Can I use French characters directly in it.

Comment: Use this website to retrieve Hex value of each char. then add a \u00 to it (and enter hex part after that) so Ê become \u00CA http://www.mikezilla.com/exp0012.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function delConfirm(key){

        if(confirm('\u00CAtes vous certain de vouloir supprimer ce client ?')){
            window.location = "deleteClient.php?e="+key;
        }

    }
</script>
```